# I keep getting TypeError: count_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a little counter app, but I seem to get stuck when trying to create an actual button which makes the counter go up.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class CounterClass(Frame):
    buttonFrame = Frame(height=200, width=200)
    counterStatus = Label(buttonFrame, text="0")

    def count_function(self):
        i = int(self.counterStatus.cget("text"))
        i += 1
        self.counterStatus.config(text=str(i))
    counter = Button(buttonFrame, text="+1", command=count_function)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.buttonFrame.pack()
        self.counterStatus.pack()
        self.counter.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    c = CounterClass(master=root)
    c.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

When I click the button, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: count_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

However, when I create a module that should do exactly the same, but I don't use a class it works fine:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def count_function():
    i = int(counterStatus.cget("text"))
    i += 1
    counterStatus.config(text=str(i))

buttonFrame = Frame(height=200, width=200)
counterStatus = Label(buttonFrame, text="0")
counterButton = Button(buttonFrame, text="+1", command=count_function)

buttonFrame.pack()
counterStatus.pack()
counterButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a typo in your first code block. The `class CounterClass(Frame):` should be dedented 4 spaces. SO's editor requires me to change 6 characters, so I can't make the edit for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
counter = Button(buttonFrame, text="+1", command=count_function)
```

When you click the button, this will try to call the `count_function` without any argument. But since it’s an instance method, it requires the (implicit) `self` parameter.

To fix this, you should move the creation of your elements inside of the `__init__` method. This not only prevents them from being stored as (shared) class members, but will also allow you to specify bound methods:

```
class CounterClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.buttonFrame = Frame(height=200, width=200)
        self.counter = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="+1", command=self.count_function)
        self.counterStatus = Label(self.buttonFrame, text="0")
        self.pack()
```